# Removing fragment issues in android

Tags: replace, android-fragments

I am just replacing fragment to show other fragment in my application.its working fine its showing fragment2,But when try to remove it removes only my layouts not a fragment.How to remove my fragment?

P.S :When I click on home button then my fragment removed.

here is my code snippet

```c
 fragment2= new MyFragment(context, ls);
                      Bundle intent = new Bundle();
                      intent.putSerializable("lookup_response", prepareData(5));
                        lookupfragment.setArguments(intent);
                      FragmentTransaction ft= ((MyActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                      ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment2, "FrahmentTag");
                      ft.addToBackStack(null);
                           ft.commit();
```

to remove my fragment

```c
FragmentTransaction ft = ((DashBoardActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.remove(myfragment);
                        ft.commit();
```

can anyone help me what am doing wrong in this?thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi friends i solve this problem by this lines

```
 ft.add(R.id.container, fragment2, "FrahmentTag");
                      ft.addToBackStack(null);
                           ft.commit();
```

Instead of   `ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment2, "FrahmentTag");`

and when removing fragment used this

```
 getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```